# if statement allowing code to run when shouldnt

Tags: android, eclipse

Not sure why this is happening in my code as far as I can see it should be fine, though I have been at this all day.

My problem is that I have a count that increments when a checkbox is selected or decreases when unchecked with a maximum of 4 choices allowed with an alert saying you cannot choose a 5th one.

Choices 1 - 3 work fine - I output my variable to log cat and it goes up and down fine yet once I press the fourth choice and I press the 5th it allows it where I have said `premCount<=4`.

The alert shows on 6th press but allows the user to dismiss then select it again, and this continues when it shouldn't.

Here is my code:

```
public void handlePremCheckboxClick(View v){
    CheckBox tmpChkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(v.getId());
    if (premCounter<=4){ <---this part is allowing 5, 6, 7, etc presses through
        if(tmpChkBox.isChecked())
        {
            tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff33b5e5"));
            premCounter++;
        }
        if(tmpChkBox.isChecked()== false)
        {
            tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            premCounter--;
        }
    }else if(premCounter >4) {
        tmpChkBox.setChecked(false);
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        premCounter--;

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Max Teams Reached")
        .setMessage("You have selected the max of 4 Premiership teams")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
        .show(); 
    }   
    System.out.println(premCounter);

}
```

logcat:

```
10-18 17:10:58.859: D/OpenGLRenderer(25923): Enabling debug mode 0
10-18 17:11:06.146: D/dalvikvm(25923): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 125K, 2% free 9286K/9448K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
10-18 17:11:06.377: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25923): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-18 17:11:07.258: I/System.out(25923): 1
10-18 17:11:07.488: I/System.out(25923): 2
10-18 17:11:07.748: I/System.out(25923): 3
10-18 17:11:08.039: I/System.out(25923): 2
10-18 17:11:08.689: I/System.out(25923): 3
10-18 17:11:08.939: I/System.out(25923): 4
10-18 17:11:09.240: I/System.out(25923): 5
10-18 17:11:09.550: I/System.out(25923): 4
10-18 17:11:10.461: I/System.out(25923): 5
10-18 17:11:10.801: I/System.out(25923): 4
10-18 17:11:11.843: I/System.out(25923): 5
10-18 17:11:12.483: I/System.out(25923): 4
10-18 17:11:13.444: I/System.out(25923): 5
10-18 17:11:13.695: I/System.out(25923): 4
10-18 17:11:14.706: I/System.out(25923): 5
10-18 17:11:15.086: I/System.out(25923): 4
10-18 17:11:16.217: I/System.out(25923): 5
```

Comment: `}else if(premCounter >4) {` ... `premCounter--;` ?  I don't know if this is causing it or not, but it looks suspicious... anyway, when all else fails, have logcat print the value of `premCounter` at several instances.  Like as the first line of code in any `if` or `else` block and just after all of your `increment` and `decrement` lines.  In fact, move your `alert` code to print to the same area you're printing out the values of `premCounter` so you can clearly see the order of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are couple of things I can see:

**First**, you are initializing `premCounter` to 0? This means it will allow: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` which are five items..

**Second**, you decrement `premCounter` in the `else`. You should not be doing it. If 4 items have already been checked (`premCounter>=4`), then if the checkbox is already checked allow it to be unchecked and decrement counter. If it is not already checked, show alert (as now trying to check a new item)

So basically this should work:

```
public void handlePremCheckboxClick(View v)
{
    CheckBox tmpChkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(v.getId());
    if (premCounter < 4) {
        if (tmpChkBox.isChecked()) {
            tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff33b5e5"));
            premCounter++;
        }
        if (tmpChkBox.isChecked() == false) {
            tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            premCounter--;
        }
    }
    else { // 4 have already been checked, now only allow unchecking.
        tmpChkBox.setChecked(false);
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if (!tmpChkBox.isChecked()) {
            premCounter--;
        }
        else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Max Teams Reached")
                    .setMessage("You have selected the max of 4 Premiership teams")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(premCounter);

}
```

**Update:** I put the check wrong in the previous version. The explanation still remains the same.

Comment: thanks for reply, i've tested your code the 5th press doesnt allow for the check box to be checked how ever if you press any after that it allows it to be checked

Comment: I put the check wrong in the answer. Updated the code and tested it. works fine!

Comment: thanks for the assist it still checking when you double press the check box but managed to solve it ill post what i've done (when i can)